# How to change bootstrap modal dialog so that it has no animation while showing but fade outs slowly?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal dialog. I need to change it so that the modal appears quickly without any animation. But when it closes, it should fade out slowly. so, that the animation is visible.

Below is my html code for the popup.

```
<div class="modal" id="pleaseWaitPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-5x fa-spin fa-pulse" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                <p class="light-gray-pop"> Processing Your Request.</p>
                <h3> PLEASE WAIT</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and below is the js for showing the modal dialog.

```
$('#pleaseWaitPopup').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your attempts so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding/removing the `class="fade"` for the bootstrap modal. Remove the fade animation right before the modal is shown and then add it back once the modal is displayed:

```
// Remove the fade animation for the modal before the modal is shown
$('#pleaseWaitPopup').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('fade');
})

// Add the fade animation for the modal once the modal is shown
$('#pleaseWaitPopup').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).addClass('fade');
})

$('#pleaseWaitPopup').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
});
```

Here is a bootply
http://www.bootply.com/USl2vMXKCj

I added temporary close and open buttons to be able to toggle the modal but feel free to remove them as needed/